# Передача данных. C# tcpClient -> C++ tcpServer

Tags: c#, c++, сокет, tcp-ip

Проблема с передачей числа типа int. Код передачи в C#:

```
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
byte[] buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MessageBox.Text);
byte[] size_buff = BitConverter.GetBytes(buff.Length);

ns.Write(size_buff, 0, 4);
ns.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
```

Код приема в C++:

```
char size_buff[4];
int bytes_recv;
while ((bytes_recv = recv(sock, size_buff, 4, 0)) &&
    bytes_recv != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    // Тут size_buff становится равным
    // {14 '\xe', 0 '\0', 0 '\0', 0 '\0'}
    int size = atoi(size_buff);
    char* buff = new char[size];

    bytes_recv = recv(sock, buff, size, 0);

    if (bytes_recv != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        command_stack.push(buff);
    }
}
```

atoi естественно такое не преобразовывает в число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

atoi преобразовывает строковое представление числа. а вы передаете не строковое, а просто байты, из которых у вас состоит int. И на стороне C++ достаточно эти байты собрать обратно в int:

```
int size = (size_buff[3] << 24) | (size_buff[2] << 16) | (size_buff[1] << 8) | size_buff[0];
```

Comment: Отлично работает. Спасибо. А подскажите, еще, пожалуйста. Как далее корректно использовать переданный размер? Пытаюсь делать так char* buff = new char[size]; но выделяется памяти больше чем положено. В итоге переданная строка заполняется мусором.

Comment: Передача числа в виде строки имеет одно преимущество - не нужно заботиться о порядке байт.

Comment: @alexolut недостаток передачи числа в виде строки - у строкового представления переменная длина. поэтому перед передачей числа в виде строки надо передать длину этой строки. в виде числа. ну или принудительно передавать "с запасом".

Comment: Кто ж спорит, просто из-за разного порядка байт можно вообще словить не то, что передал. И это куда хуже проблемы некоторого увеличения трафика.

Comment: @alexolut согласен, по хорошему код на C# должен прогонять int через IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder для получения фиксированного порядка байт